# How to create "macros" for Excel workbooks running as an app on MS Teams

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-teams

Please point me to some resources to teach me how to create Excel "macros" that will run when the workbook is an app on MS Teams.  I am aware that VBA does not run on workbooks in the cloud, and I understand that a cloud based workbook can contain a macro that will run once the document is opened in Excel (local).  What I am looking for is the technology used to write a script/macro/whatever-you-call-it that will run on cloud/Teams/SharePoint.

I suspect my terrible search results on the subject are a result on me not knowing the correct terminology or technology.

Comment: Check out Office Scripts https://www.excelquicker.com/resources/news-sheet/office-scripts-samples-and-scenarios/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the Excel JavaScript API. It's not really a macro and not really a good idea either. They are called "add-ins" now. They have to be uploaded and then run from a task pane. The Microsoft tutorial is quite long so I won't be giving an example here.

TUTORIAL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial

It quite complicated and convoluted. It would be much easier to just open the file from Teams and run VBA code.

Comment: Thanks for this. I believe it is what I am looking for, but not what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Office Scripts
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/office-scripts/info

This is Microsoft's natural successor to VBA spreadsheet automation and macros for the modern foundation of Excel.

Initially it was available only in Excel for Web, but is now also available in desktop versions of Excel.

It's based on TypeScript and shares similarities with JavaScript.

There is not (yet?) any inbuilt translation to or from VBA, nor is that expected anytime soon (if ever).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article comparing VBA with the Office Scripts: http://digitalmill.net/2023/06/10/office-scripts-the-new-vba/

You also can connect both products (Excel and Teams) by using the Microsoft Power Automate.